# How to fix the problem about unknown source in array list?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I need to get all the descendants of a node of a tree. For that I have written a function that needs a helping function. When I want to get the results, I am getting these errors:

at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)

I already had that error, that's why I created different lists for every method: children, descendants, ancestors, elements and positions. Now I have errors everywhere.

```
public List<Position<E>> descendants(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {
    if(p == null || isEmpty())
            throw new InvalidPositionException();
    // remove all positions from list
    descendantList.removeAll(descendantList);
    return descendantsList(p);
}
```

```
public List<Position<E>> descendantsList(Position<E> p) {
    if(isInternal(p)) {
        // add child to list and check if the child has also children
        for(Position<E> child : children(p)) {
            descendantList.add(child);
            // if child has also children
            if(isInternal(child))
                descendantsList(child);
        }
    }
    return descendantList;
}
```

The children function looks like that:

```
public List<Position<E>> children(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {
    if(p == null || isEmpty())
        throw new InvalidPositionException();
    else {
        BinaryTreeNode<E> node = (BinaryTreeNode<E>) p;
        childrenList.removeAll(childrenList);
        // add left child first
        if(node.leftChild != null)
            childrenList.add(node.leftChild);
        if(node.rightChild != null)
            childrenList.add(node.rightChild);
        return childrenList;
    }
}
```

For that I created different lists:

```
- ArrayList for children: childrenList
- ArrayList for descendants: descendantsList
```

How can I solve this error?

Edit: I replaced all removeAll with clear. It worked for this method descendants, but as an example, I still have the same error for my height method:

```
public int height() throws EmptyTreeException {
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyTreeException();
    else
        return heightOf(root);
}
```

```
private int heightOf(Position<E> p) {
    if(isExternal(p))
        return 0;
    else {
        int h = 0;
        for(Position<E> child : children(p)) {
            h = Math.max(h,heightOf(child));
        }
        return h + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop modifying the List object(s) that you're in the middle of looping through

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `removeAll(childrenList)`. Use `clear()`. First of all it's faster, second of all, that might be where you're getting your error. `removeAll()` steps through the provided Collection and removes elements in the Collection that called it. In your case that's the same collection.

EDIT: Ok. I see what's going on. I had to implement it myself to see.

Basically what happens is you call `height(root)`. This iterates through the tree and find's `heightOf` each node and returns that.

in your `heightOf` method you have a for loop that uses recursion.

The for loop calls `children(node)` which clears out the list `childrenList` and then repopulates it.

The problem is in the first iteration `childrenList` is assigned some values. Then you call `heightOf` again, while still referencing a `Position<E>`  located in `childrenList` (you call this `Position<E>` child). When `heightOf` is called again on child, `childrenList` is modified again. Since you are still holding a reference to `Position<E>` in `childrenList` and you try to delete or change this reference you get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You can fix this by changing your `children` method to something like:

```
public List<Position<E>> children(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException {
    List<Position<E>> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    if(p == null || isEmpty()) {
        throw new InvalidPositionException();
    }else {
        BinaryTreeNode<E> node = (BinaryTreeNode<E>) p;
        // add left child first
        if(node.leftChild != null) {
            returnList.add(node.leftChild);
        }
        if(node.rightChild != null) {
            returnList.add(node.rightChild);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

In order to maintain a `childrenList` of all nodes in the tree you will probably need to make a new method and just call that method once. That method will look very similar to your current `children` method but you can call it recursively on each node's left and right child.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I tried that and it worked for the descendants method. But I still have the same error for my height method. You can see this one in my post above.

Comment: can you post the entire stack trace? the 2 lines you posted don't give much info besides theres a ConcurrentModificationException. The entire stacktrace should pinpoint where the problem is coming from

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
 at project4.classes.LinkedBinaryTree.heightOf(LinkedBinaryTree.java:111)
 at project4.classes.LinkedBinaryTree.heightOf(LinkedBinaryTree.java:112)
 at project4.classes.LinkedBinaryTree.heightOf(LinkedBinaryTree.java:112)
 at project4.classes.LinkedBinaryTree.height(LinkedBinaryTree.java:97)
 at project4.classes.Main.main(Main.java:41)

Comment: Error heigth, line 97: return heightOf(root);
Error heigthOf, line 111: for(Position<E> child : children(p)) {
Error heightOf, line 112: h = Math.max(h,heightOf(child));

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like that:
I created a new List for every method that uses a children list. With that I didn't get the following error:

at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)